# Lista principal vazia dentro do loop

Tags: python, lógica

Quando uso uma variável para pegar os últimos dados de uma lista, a lista principal perde os dados.

```
valores= list()
resp=" "
valores2= list()

while True:
    valores.append(str(input('digite um nome')))
    valores2=valores.pop()
    resp= str(input('S ou N')).strip.upper()
    if resp =="N":
        break

print(f'valores1 {valores} valores 2 {valores2}')
```

Comment: Se ler a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), verá que `valores.pop()` **remove** um valor da lista.

Comment: Solucionado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A função `pop` apaga o valor(es) da lista, se o objetivo for copiar, use `copy`, desta maneira `valores_dois = valores.copy()`. Caso queira descrever o que está tentado fazer, eu posso ajudar.